# Optimize query get total call duration of day per subscriber

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have view HW02 created from table `call_details` having following structure.

`pri_key | calling_no | called_no | answer_date_time | Duration`

and I have to find total duration called by each subscriber on a day. 
and create view as

```
create view hw02 as 
select calling_no, day(answer_date_time) as days,duration from call_details;
```

and I calculate total_duration of each subscriber per days as

```
select a.calling_no,a.days,sum(b.duration) 
from hw02 as a, hw02 as b 
where a.calling_no=b.calling_no and a.days=b.days;
```

This query takes lots of time to execute. So my question is how to optimize this query. (Data :- around 150,000 rows)

Comment: you can apply partition by date and then aggregate duration on calling_no... I think it will be better than comparing between value of 2 alices..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, should be faster and serve your purpose

```
SELECT
  calling_no, 
  DATE(answer_date_time) as day,
  SUM( duration ) 
FROM 
  call_details
GROUP BY
  calling_no,
  DATE(answer_date_time)
```

A `self-join` on the `view` itself is not needed in your case, all we want is the total duration a `user` calls to other `users`, grouped by the `date`.

The `call` duration, I suppose for a particular `call` would be same for the `called` and the `calling` `user` (records). The `day()` function used by you, would not return the right `results`, if you have data for multiple months, hence I have used the `date` function instead

more on datetime functions in mysql, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html